# How to stop seaborn despine removing y tick marks on second axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am encountering a problem when using despine() with seaborn. I am trying to use two y axes, and am only removing the neccesary spines for each axis, but despine() also removes the tick marks from the right hand vertical axis. A minimum working example is below:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

seaborn.set()
seaborn.set_style("ticks")

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,2))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(np.array([0,1,3]))
ax2.plot(np.array([2,2,1]))

seaborn.despine(ax=ax2, left=True, right=False, trim="True")
seaborn.despine(ax=ax1, bottom=True, left=False, right=True, trim="true")

plt.show()
```

As you can see in the image below, this has also removed the tick marks from the right hand vertical axis (which I do not want).

[image]

Any insights into how I would fix this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way `twinx` is implemented, the ticks on the second y axis actually belong to the "left" spine, so you need

```py
seaborn.despine(ax=ax2, left=False, right=False, trim="True")
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, although I've now realised there's a slight issue: despine now no longer trims the left hand axis for ax2. A solution that fixes this is to use 

ax2.tick_params(axis='y', right=True)

after despine in the original code.

Comment: Yes, or despine the left axis for `ax1`.